# Prometheus Query to identify changes for a metrics

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

My Prometheus Query returns me following metrics data Say(Machine status)

```
+-------+------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------+
| Time  | Machine group = "A", Machine name ="one" |   Machine group = "A", Machine name = "two" |
+-------+------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------+
| 00:00 | Down                                     | -                                           |
| 00:01 | -                                        | UP                                          |
| 00:02 | Down                                     | -                                           |
| 00:03 | UP                                       | -                                           |
+-------+------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------+
```

I am trying out how many times Machine group  has went down (from UP to Down) and (Down to UP).

Is there any we can achieve in the prometheus Query.

Thank you

Comment: The dataset in your example: Does it match the data in Prometheus or the data generated and instrumented?

Answer (score 0):

The [changes()](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#changes) function takes `range-vector` as input. Proper use of [range-vector-selector](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#range-vector-selectors) should fix your problem.

Updated query:

```
changes(sh:wls_status_status{prd_pod="cddn-test-mc",wlsname="ess_soaserver_ha"}[7d])
```

Comment: Hi,

changes(sh:wls_status_status{prd_pod="cddn-test-mc",wlsname="ess_soaserver_ha"}[$__range])

But no help

Comment: I have data also like 1 - - - 1 - - , is there any way to count toggle between these two

Comment: @akshay does `sh:wls_status_status{prd_pod="cddn-test-mc",wlsname="ess_soaserver_ha"}[$__range]` this query return your test data? If not, your test data representation is not perfect.

Comment: Yes sir, This will return test data as 1 - - - - - - 1 - - - - , Dashes means no data for that timestamp

Comment: Ex:  12:00 -> 1  , 12:01 -> 1, 12:02 -> - , 12:03 -> - , 12:04 -> 1